# MySQL Error: Table doesn't exist in engine, can't discard tablespace, can't create table with same name for a foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm fairly new to mysql and html/php.

This is the long, more in detail version, of my problem, I'll put a summary at the end of the post:

I've been developing a site in local using xampp, so I used phpmyadmin for the DDL part of development.
Problems started when in my php code I passed a variable from one page to another in an incorrect way it seems (this value should have been something like 0000000001 and instead it was 0). In this script, this value was used in an INSERT INTO query. Problem is that the value we're talking about was inserted in a column with a foreign key constraint, but this value didn't point to any primary key in the father table (I'm guessing this was the problem since this is where it all started going downhill). Suddenly the table in phpmyadmin was marked as "in use" and I started getting the error #1932 "table doesn't exist in engine". So I tried to drop it and discard tablespace: the DROP TABLE worked fine (the table disappear from the db view, even though it kept showing errno 1932), but I could not discard tablespace since it kept telling me that the table didn't exist. In mysql files I could see the .frm file gone, but not the .ibd. So I tried to delete it manually in order to be able to create this table once again (because if I tried to recreate it I was told to discard the tablespace first, but it's insane since I cannot discard it because I keep being told that the table does not exist). If I try to create again the table using the phpmyadmin UI I get the error #1005 that reference the error #150. So checking online I get the idea that I have to recreate the table exactly as it was, so from console I write down the CREATE TABLE query, including the foreign key constraint as shown in the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section of the error log, but instead I get the error #121.

**SO, SUMMARIZING:**
I want to make this table accessible to my code and myself again or create it again.

The table is marked in use and I can't access it.
If I try to drop it and discard tablespace I get error #1932.
If I try to recreate it I get errors because it already exixts, because I have to discard tablespace first or because I have a foreign key constraint incorrectly formed.
If I try to recreate it specifing the constraint I get an error because the constraint already exists.

This is the query I used to create the table specifing the constraint

```
CREATE TABLE `dbsmartcity`.`copertura` ( 
    `Luogo` INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL ,
    `Rete` INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `copertura_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Luogo`) REFERENCES `luoghi` (`IDLuogo`) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

- Yes, I have restarted MySQL.
- Yup, I explicitly dropped the tablespace.
- I would like to keep the remove/reinstall option as a last resort.

Sorry if I was not clear somewhere in this post. Please help me, my exam is near. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Delete (and recreate) your foreign key index on the other table?

Comment: Or What about simply create a new table with a different name?

Comment: Or try to restart MySQL which will [flush the MySQL caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373399/flush-innodb-cache) , which may help

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212808/1548. When I had a similar issue, the only way I could fix it was to remove (and purge) MySQL, and then reinstall.

Comment: Ddi you actually explicitly [Drop the TABLESPACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-tablespace.html)? *Tablespaces are not deleted automatically. A tablespace must be dropped explicitly using DROP TABLESPACE. DROP DATABASE has no effect in this regard, even if the operation drops all tables belonging to the tablespace.*

Comment: I can create a new table with a different name obviously, but I would not understand what is the actual problem here.
Yes, I restarted MySQL.
Yup, I explicitly dropped the tablespace.
I would like to keep the remove/reinstall option as a last resort.